# Remove duplicate rows in the following scenario

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table with the following values

```
id   |  desc |   code |     userId       
----------------------------------
12   |   ABC |    005 |     user12 
13   |   ABC |    005 |     user12
14   |   ABC |    005 |     user12
15   |   ABC |    005 |     user12
21   |   XYZ |    005 |     user13 
22   |   XYZ |    005 |     user13
24   |   XYZ |    005 |     user13
25   |   XYZ |    005 |     user13
```

I'd like to write a SQL to get the distinct `(id, desc , code, userId)` values from the above table (here the user can get any one of the 4 Ids (among 12, 13, 14,15) for userId `user12`).

**Expected result**(ignore the first column as it can by any one of the 4 values)

```
12   |   ABC |    005 |     user12 
21   |   XYZ |    005 |     user13
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select min(t.id), t.desc, t.code, t.userId 
from myTable t
group by t.desc, t.code, t.userId
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `SELECT MAX(id) (...) GROUP BY desc , code, userId`?